# How generate an M..N range with a wrapper for RandomRange 0..N-1? Understanding an existing implementation

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

Need help with creating an improved version of the RandomRange procedure called BetterRandomRange. RandomRange produces an integer between 0 and N - 1. For the BetterRandomRange procedure, I have to make it generate a number between M and N (m is passed in EBX, and N in EAX).

I found a code block from the internet, but I don't understand what's happening in it. Can anyone please explain it?

```
.code

main PROC


mov ebx, -300       ; lower bound (m)
mov  eax, 100       ; upper bound (n)
call BetterRandomRange
call WriteInt

;; Editor's note: missing ret
;; so main falls through into a tailcall to BetterRandomRange

BetterRandomRange PROC
    sub ebx, eax
    xchg ebx, eax
    call RandomRange
    neg ebx
    sub eax, ebx
    call writeint
    ret
BetterRandomRange ENDP
```

Why is the "neg ebx" instruction necessary? Why do we need to make EBX negative?

Comment: `neg ebx` before `sub eax, ebx` is not necessary; it's a missed optimization for `add eax, ebx` because  `eax -= -ebx` is the same as `eax += ebx`.  WriteInt only cares about EAX as an input so leaving a different value in EBX doesn't matter.  As far as the algorithm it's implementing, think about how you can range-shift a 0..x range to get an m..n range.

Comment: hmm I don't get it cause how do I shift the 0 to x when I can't access the 0 in RandomRange. You only give it one value and that's that N value. How do I even access the 0 to shift it to M?? Do I need to utilize the stack and push EAX and EBX? Very confused :(

Comment: Think about how adding or subtracting maps each number in the 0..x range to a different number in a range of the same length that doesn't start at 0.  i.e. what algorithm you would use to implement this function in a high-level language.

Comment: I've never used a wrapper, but I'll look into it thanks

Comment: `BetterRandomRange` *is* a wrapper function around `RandomRange`.  It builds M..N range functionality on top of that 0..x-1 functionality without actually having to do implement its own random number generator.

Comment: i'm still very stuck on this problem and also very confused. will try again tomorrow haha thank you for all your help :)

Comment: IDK how to give any more hints without just doing your homework for you (and spending a bunch of time writing up example inputs and possible return values).  I suggest you talk to your instructor; they're in a better position to guide you step by step through basic concepts and logic and it's literally their job.